# Css manipulation with jquery and Json data

Tags: jquery, html, css, json

I was wondering if it is posible to import some number out of a extern Jsonfile. To take Data from the Jsonfile is no problem and also the use but if i try to change with a function put instead a "real" number I tried to put a value into the place for the css property. like this ->

```css
body{
font-size: 16px;
margin: 1rem auto;
width: 100px;
}
.value_height{
width:2rem;
height: 2rem;
background-color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="value_height">
  </div>
  
  <script>
  $.getJSON('data/jasonfile.json', function(data) {
    for (var i in data.results) {
                            $(".value_height").css("\"+data.results[i].duration_ratio+\""); 
                            
   for(var j in data.results[i].sub_paths)$(".value_height").css(+data.results[i].duration_ratio +);
                            }
  });
  </script>
</body>
```

Jsonfile:
{ "results":[ { "duration_ratio":"0.560849598163031", "sub_paths":[ { "duration_ratio":"0.038894575230296824" } ] } ] }

I would be grateful if somebody has an idea how to fix this problem! :)

Comment: Firstly it's really not clear what you're trying to achieve. Secondly, you're using the getter of `css()` but not setting the result to a variable...?

Comment: Well, you don't need `"` >> `$(".value_height").css(data.results[i].duration_ratio);`. But you need to set somehting in css function. `.css('propertyName', 'value')` which is missing in your code.

Comment: I´m aming to get variable heights depending on the data from the jsonfile. -> no varibales because the Jsonfile can change and i want it to run with out variables, is this possible?

Comment: It's possible, but we need more information in order to help you, such as the  `data` object and its values, along with the HTML. Right now your logic (when fixed syntactically) will just repeatedly get a value from the first `.value_height` element in the DOM and do nothing with it